# Openlayers: Bing ordnance survey map

Tags: openlayers, bing-maps

I'm using openlayers to display maps. I can display a Bing Road map layer, but when I add an Ordnance Survey layer (by changing `road` to `ordnancesurvey`) the layer displays but I get the following error:

```
Error: TypeError: providers is null
Source File: http://www.cabotscouts.org.uk/scripts/openlayers-2.12/OpenLayers.debug.js Line: 39605
```

Demo: http://www.cabotscouts.org.uk/scripts/test.html

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to get that error when changing to any map style - it's not specific to the OS style...

Comment: But the error goes away if I don't add the OS layer: http://www.cabotscouts.org.uk/scripts/test2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Bing doesn't provide imageryProviders (which has the attribution info) for OS, which causes the problem when OL tries to access it.

I've hacked my Openlayers.debug.js file to return if the providers is null (around line 39606)

```
if (!providers)
{
    return;
}
```